# How to redirect user with system message in Joomla 3

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-api, redirect, deprecated

I know that you can achieve this by doing:

`JFactory::getApplication->redirect(url, message, type)`

but the documentation at

[JFactory::getApplication](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JApplication.html)

says it is deprecated and suggest to use `enqueueMessage` that is also deprecated and that doesn't redirect you for example to home page.

How can I redirect an user to home page with system message using methods that are not deprecated. Documentation says they will (?) be deprecated in version 4 of Joomla, so is the current method the only one or is there already a new one standard method to achieve this?

**Edit:**
These methods aren't deprecated on JApplicationCms (Joomla libraries), but are deprecated on JApplication (Joomla Plaftorm). So since `JFactory::getApplication` returns JApplicationCms object, then the methods like `redirect` and `enqueueMessage` aren't deprecated and using them is the correct way to redirect with message.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Passing the message via the redirect function is deprecated, but both `redirect()` and `enqueueMessage()` are still both fine to use on their own.

You simply need to use both together, like so:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();

$app->enqueueMessage('Redirect to another page was successful', 'success');
$app->redirect(JRoute::_('index.php'));
```

`enqueueMessage` stores the message in a session, so when you call this before the `redirect()` function, the session value still exists on the page you were redirected to, thus the message will display ;)

Comment: Actually this is a better solution because since Joomla! 3.2 `JFactory::getApplication()` returns a JApplicationCms object instead of deprecated JApplication

Comment: True these methods aren't deprecated on JApplicationCms (Joomla libraries), but are deprecated on JApplication (Joomla Plaftorm). Documentation [link](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JFactory.html#method_getApplication) says it returns JApplicationCms (link doesn't work) and says to see JApplication where these methods are deprecated. So it's documentation confusion and I will signalize this problem, so it can be fixed.

Answer (score 4):

The best thing to do is to handle all redirects directly in sub controllers where you just need to use `$this->setRedirect($url,$msg,$type);` and MVC will do the rest of the job.

If you need to redirect outside of controllers you can use **JControllerLegacy** class:

```
$controller = JControllerLegacy::getInstance("ComponentName");
$controller->setRedirect($url,$msg,$type);
$controller->redirect();
```